# Binding C# BindingList<T> to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datasource, bindinglist

Maybe the question is a little bit dumb, but I did not quite find solution anywhere else.
So I am using a `BindingList` of custom made class objects as a `DataSource` for `DataGridView`.
Everything works fine with properties, that are directly inherited from other classes, but if I have an object of other class in the main class, its properties wont show up in `DataGridView`.

Classes are:

```
enum Valsts
{
    Latvija,
    Igaunija,
    Ķīna,
    ASV
}
class Razotajs
{
    public Valsts valsts { get; set; }
    public string razotajaNosaukums { get; set; }
}
class Tehnika
{
    public string krasa { get; set; }
    public Razotajs razotajs = new Razotajs();
}
class Viedierice : Tehnika
{
    public string operetajsistema { get; set; }
    public double ekranaIzmers { get; set; }
    public bool irHDMI { get; set; }
}
class MobilaisTelefons : Viedierice
{
    public string modelis { get; set; }
    public double svars { get; set; }
    public SimKarte sim = new SimKarte();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(";", modelis.ToString(),svars.ToString(),sim.veids.ToString(),operetajsistema.ToString(),ekranaIzmers.ToString(),irHDMI.ToString(),krasa.ToString(),razotajs.razotajaNosaukums.ToString(),
            sim.numurs.ToString(),razotajs.valsts.ToString());
    }
}
class SimKarte
{
    public string veids { get; set;}
    public int numurs { get; set; }
}
```

For example- I can see columns "modelis" and "svars", but attributes like "veids" and "numurs" from class `SimKarte` are not included in the `DataGridView`.

Is there any solution for this?
I've tried to add `{ get; set; }` after declaring a new instance of an object in the class, but it's not even a real thing. I really don't have any idea, what would help me to solve this.

Thank you all in advance! :)

Comment: Very hard to know what those foreign language actors are, but the basic answer is that a DGV simply knows how to display an `int` or `single` or `DateTime` etc etc etc.  It wont know what to do with a `razotajs`.  You of course can write converter code to display it if it makes sense to display it in a DGV cell.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Ok, I got that. 
Can you please give me some example of that converter code you are writing about? I've never done that..

Comment: In the `MobilaisTelefons` class add the properties you want to display in the grid from the `SimKarte` class. Something like… `public string Veids => sim.veids;` and `public int Numurs => sim.numurs;`

Comment: What are you expecting it will look like?

Comment: @CaiusJard I was expecting, that `DataGridView` will include all attributes of classes, that are listed above. 
As I mentioned, I have a `BindingList` with `Mobilais_telefons` class objects, and I needed to display information about every single object of the `BindingList` in the `DataGridView`.

Comment: Ah.. no.. it doesn't recurse into objects

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think the simplest solution is the one JohnG proposed; add proxy properties to your main class that read/write the properties of the complex objects

A datagridview will show only the simple types it knows how to show, from the top level class. It will not dig into properties of properties (otherwise even adding a string column would cause the grid to fill up with a Length column an Isinterned column etc..)

```
partial class MobilaisTelefons : Viedierice
{
    public string modelis { get; set; }
    public double svars { get; set; }
    public SimKarte sim { get; set; } = new SimKarte();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(";",
          modelis, svars, sim.veids, operetajsistema, ekranaIzmers, irHDMI, krasa, razotajs.razotajaNosaukums,
            sim.numurs, razotajs.valsts);
    }
}

partial class MobilaisTelefons {
    public string SimVeids { get => sim.veids; set => sim.veids = value; }
    public string SimNumers { get => sim.numers; set => sim.numers = value; }
    public string RazotajsRazotajaNosaukums { get => razotajs.razotajaNosaukums; set => razotajs.razotajaNosaukums = value; }

    public Valsts RazotajsValsts { get => razotajs.valsts; set => razotajs.valsts = value; }
}
```

Few tips:

- I made the extension of the class partial so you can put it in another file. Hiding its members from intellisense would be hard work
- the Enum column will probably show as an int. if you want it to be sensible, use a DataGridViewComboBox column bound to a list of all the enum values/names. On the column, set the DataMember to `"RazotajsValsts"`, the DataSource to the list of enums, the DisplayMember to the property representing the enum name and the ValueMember to the property representing the enum value. See Enum.GetValues.
- Enums should only have a plural name (if valsts is plural) if they are flags
- classes should not have a plural name
- public properties names should be in PascalCase not camelCase
- I simplified your tostring: you don't need to call to string on everything; string join will do it. You especially don't need to call tostring on a string